# Python shutil copying option per file vs folder

Tags: python, shutil

I am doing a series of copies - some folders and their contents, some files.  Seems you use `shutil.copytree` for folders and contents, and `shutil.copy` for files.  I had started to put all these copies into one `src-dst` dictionary in order to loop through and process all at once, but then ran up against folder vs file.  Of course I can separate operations, but is there a pythonic way to keep it all in one loop?  If `x` is a file, do `copy`; if `x` is a folder, do `copytree`.
Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if a given path is for a file or a directory?  So you can write a function that uses the correct call based on its results?

Comment: Yes, that'd work, testing for file versus directory.  How?  Or, any other way that makes more sense.

Comment: I'll use this, just found https://pythonexamples.org/python-check-if-path-is-file-or-directory/